# texture (image) on text in flutter

Tags: image, text, flutter, textures, foreground

is there a way to put image (texture) on a text in Flutter?

like the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 6):

the operation of drawing image on text is asynchronous, because it waits for the image to be loaded and set it on the `TextStyle`'s foreground shader.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

String textureName = "images/texture.jpg";
 Future<TextStyle> textureText(TextStyle textStyle,
    ) async {
  ui.Image img;
  img = await ImageLoader.load(textureName);
  Float64List matrix4 = new Matrix4.identity().storage;
  return textStyle.copyWith(
      foreground: Paint1()
        ..shader = ImageShader(img, TileMode.mirror, TileMode.mirror, matrix4));
}
```

below, `FutureBuilder` calls `textureText` and use the returned `TextStyle`

```
  Widget tt = new FutureBuilder<TextStyle>(
    future: texturedText(
        TextStyle(fontSize: 70.0,), // a Future<String> or null
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<TextStyle> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return new Text('Awaiting result...');
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          else
            return new Text(
              'TEXTURE',
              style: snapshot.data,
            );
      }
    },
  );
```

you can use `tt` (texturedText) like a normal widget.

A [complete example](https://github.com/bluemix/Gradient-Screens/blob/master/lib/pages/be_kind_page.dart) is also available in this [repo](https://github.com/bluemix/Gradient-Screens).

Comment: Thank, when I am dragging this text it seems that texture is also moving.

Comment: i think because it is laid-out on the text, so, when there is a text displacement, the texture will have the same displacement too.

Comment: Can you give me any idea how to do for the draggble widget?

Comment: actually, the texture is not moving, the texture if fixed at there own position. But it seems that texture is moving.