# Flutter texture text with File Image

Tags: flutter

How do I texture a Text widget using an image that's already loaded into a File/Image.file?
I'm trying to use the ShaderMask widget but I have no idea how to properly create an ImageShader for that...

I've searched on how to do this, but can't find an appropriate answer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066476/texture-image-on-text-in-flutter) seems outdated.

As @pskink has mentioned, I've tried using decodeImageFromList using an Int8List and a completer callback, however, that gives me a

```
error: native function 'instantiateImageCodec' (5 arguments) cannot be found
```

error... It might be worth to mention that I'm calling this from a compute, which starts an isolate.

Comment: *"[...] but I have no idea how to properly create an ImageShader for that..."* - you need `Image` object, get it with [decodeImageFromList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/decodeImageFromList.html)

Comment: @pskink updated the question. I've tried doing that but it returns an error.

Comment: most likely you have wrong input data, what are first 16 bytes (in hex)? compare them with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: how do I check the hex?

Comment: `print()` first 16 bytes of your list in hex format https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toRadixString.html, what do you see?

Comment: dc d8 e6 e4 de c0 b7 ce ac bf a4 e6 e4 c8 ec bb

Comment: it is not jpeg, png, webp, gif - what kind of image data do you pass?

Comment: I use https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker to get an image from the library/camera which returns a `File`. Then I use decodeImage (package:image/image.dart) to get the Image object.

Comment: so it seems that it is not any image file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216501/discussion-between-mitch-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink Would it be possible to achieve this (textured effect) by using some sort of an image mask / or blend mode (having an image widget over the text)? Not via ShaderMask