# Is there a way to show image inside text in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, text, mask, clip

I have this code to show an image inside text in flutter but when I'm using ImageShader.
I'm getting this error
**The method 'asset' isn't defined for the type 'Image'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'asset'**

I have also referred to this [Repo](https://github.com/bluemix/Gradient-Screens). This repo link was given in previously asked question on StackOverflow about ImageShader.
I know "dart:ui" doesn't contain any asset method. So I used Image.asset but when I used this method I got this error.

> The argument type 'Image (where Image is defined in
> /Users/username/Developement/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart)'
> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image (where Image is defined
> in
> /Users/username/Developement/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/painting.dart)'

[Link to the similar question asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066476/texture-image-on-text-in-flutter)

```
 import 'dart:ui' as ui;    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Float64List matrix4 = new Matrix4.identity().storage;
  ui.Image img;

  Future<ui.Image> getImage() async{
    img = await ui.Image.asset("assets/images/ob_girl_cropped.png"); // This Line Is showing error. Please Help.
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getImage(),
            builder: (context, snapshot)
            {
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return Text(
                  'Greetings, planet!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    foreground: Paint()
                      ..shader = ImageShader(
                          img,
                          TileMode.clamp,
                          TileMode.clamp,
                          matrix4),
                  ),
                );
              }
              else{
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer you linked uses `img = await ImageLoader.load(...);`, not `img = await ui.Image.asset(...)`

Comment: ImageLoader Code in that link was wrong. Even documentation doesn't contain any detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The way you load image, which I wrote a `loadImageFromFile` helper funtion
2. You should not put `getImage()` directly in to `future` field, because flutter will create a new future every time you rebuild the page (so load the image multiple times)

Full Code:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Float64List matrix4 = new Matrix4.identity().storage;
  Future<ui.Image> imgFuture;

  // New helper function
  Future<ui.Image> loadImageFromFile(String path) async {
    var fileData = Uint8List.sublistView(await rootBundle.load(path));
    return await decodeImageFromList(fileData);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    imgFuture = loadImageFromFile("assets/images/ob_girl_cropped.png"); // Works now
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: imgFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(
                  'Greetings, planet!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    foreground: Paint()..shader = ImageShader(snapshot.data, TileMode.clamp, TileMode.clamp, matrix4),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```